# how to change image opacity within Image() widget - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image

So am trying to change image opacity using the opacity property i found in `Image()` widget, this is a short code to be clear :

```
Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Center(
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                child: Image(
                  image: NetworkImage(challengeImage),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  height: 150,
                  width: 350,
                  opacity: //not sure how to use
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

the image is a network image i retrieved from Firestore and am not sure what is the value i should put if its not double in order to apply opacity on the image. i thought to create a stack and insert asset image as a layer above my image and use the filter property but i would really like to know how the opacity can work with my code above, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AlwaysStoppedAnimation` or create an `Animation<double>`

```dart
Image(
  image: NetworkImage(""),
  opacity: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(.1),
),
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can also use animation controller.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution : wrap the widget with `Opacity` Widget
it accepts a double value in range [0,1] where 1 is fully displaying and 0 is not

Comment: i Would choose your answer it is a great one and nice technique, but Yeasin gives a direct answer to opacit usage within Image() widget, Thank you anyway.